# Why is my Move-Item command filtering not detected?

Tags: windows, powershell

My command to move all rar files

```
Move-Item -Path * -Filter *.rar -Destination .\Target
```

I changed a little bit

```
Move-Item -Path * -Filter .\*.rar -Destination .\NewTarget
```

Same issue again,rar is not filtered.

Everything is moved to Target(all files). Why?

Comment: `-Filter` works on the file **Name** only. By changing that to `.\*.rar` you are trying to have it filter on the FullName (path + filename)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should to the work :-)

It is better to filter them before with Get-ChildItem and store them at some variable. And then when you know that you have exact files just doing it with ForEach or ForEach-Object

```
$Source = "C:\Users\Puzo\Desktop\FolderA"
$Destination = "C:\Users\Puzo\Desktop\FolderB"

$FilesToMove = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter "*.rar" -Recurse
$i = 1

ForEach ($File in $FilesToMove)
{
    Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination ("$Destination\" + $File.Name)
    Write-Host ('File ' + $File.Name + 'was moved.') -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $i++
}

Write-Host "$i files was moved!" -ForegroundColor Green
```